# Speaker Diarization Offline Python with Huggingface without Authorization

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to Speeker Diarization offline using Hugging face Model. But it shows error while using it with Pyannote.audio package. Below is the picture shows saved model from huggingface.

Error:"HFValidationError: Repo id must be in the form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_name': 'Path to Saved Offline models/HuggingFace_Offline/'. Use `repo_type` argument if needed"

[image]

The code i am trying is:

```
from pyannote.audio import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline.from_pretrained("Path to Saved Offline models/HuggingFace_Offline/")
# apply pipeline and dump RTTM
diarization = pipeline("audio.wav")
```

If any changes in above code how can i modify the code?
Thanks

Comment: u cant use Speaker Diarization Offline Python with Huggingface without Authorization